# Lucene query on external fields

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have these two pojos:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(
        columnNames = {"ITEM_CODE", "ITEM_CODE_VERSION"}
))
@Indexed
@AnalyzerDef(name = "customAnalyzer", tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory =    LetterTokenizerFactory.class),
    filters = {
            @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
    })
public class Item implements Serializable {
@Field
private String brand;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "item_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "item_generator",sequenceName = "ITEM_SEQ")
@Column(name = "ITEM_ID")
private Integer id;

@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
@FieldBridge(impl = IntegerBridge.class)
@Column(name = "ITEM_CODE")
private Integer itemCode;

@Column(name = "ITEM_CODE_VERSION")
private Integer itemCodeVersion;

@Column(name="TXT_MODULE_NAME")
@Field
private String moduleName;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@IndexedEmbedded
private Set<CriticalComponent> criticalComponents = new HashSet<>();

//getters and setters
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CRITICAL_COMPONENT")
@Indexed
public class CriticalComponent implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "crit_comp_generator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "crit_comp_generator",sequenceName = "CRIT_COMP_SEQ")
@Column(name = "CRITICAL_COMPONENT_ID")
private Integer id;

@ContainedIn
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns(value = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_CODE", referencedColumnName = "ITEM_CODE"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_CODE_VERSION", referencedColumnName = "ITEM_CODE_VERSION")
})
private Item item;

@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
@Column(name = "CRITICAL_FILENAME")
private String criticalFilename;

//getters and setters
```

I have a relationship from Item OneToMany to CriticalComponent and I want to build a lucene query to search a CriticalComponent(2nd pojo) by ItemCode that is a field from Item but when I hit the search button from the view it will give me this error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
>   Unable to find field itemCode in io.package.CriticalComponent.

Here is the hibernate search service:

```
@Transactional
public List<CriticalComponent> searchForCriticalComponent(String     searchTerm){

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager =     Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    QueryBuilder qb =   fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(CriticalComponent.class).get();
    //Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1).withPrefixLength(1).onFields("criticalFilename", "itemCode", "serviceName").matching(searchTerm).createQuery();
    Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().wildcard().onFields("criticalFilename","itemCode").matching(searchTerm.toLowerCase()+'*').createQuery();

    javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, CriticalComponent.class);

    List<CriticalComponent> criticalComponentsModel = null;
    try {
        criticalComponentsModel  = jpaQuery.getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        log.debug("Search: No result found");
    }
    return criticalComponentsModel;
}
```

How can I search by itemcode from the criticalcomponent class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

Here the changes:

Item.java looks the same but it must have @ContainedIn annotation

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "item", fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
@ContainedIn
private Set<CriticalComponent> criticalComponents = new HashSet<>();
```

CriticalComponent.java the same but must have @IndexEmbedded annotation

```
@IndexedEmbedded
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns(value = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_CODE", referencedColumnName = "ITEM_CODE"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "ITEM_CODE_VERSION", referencedColumnName = "ITEM_CODE_VERSION")
})
private Item item;
```

Hibernate Search Service looks on the relationship field accessed by a dot:

```
@Transactional
public List<CriticalComponent> searchForCriticalComponent(String searchTerm){

    FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
    QueryBuilder qb = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory().buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(CriticalComponent.class).get();
    //Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().fuzzy().withEditDistanceUpTo(1).withPrefixLength(1).onFields("criticalFilename", "itemCode", "serviceName").matching(searchTerm).createQuery();
    Query luceneQuery = qb.keyword().wildcard().onFields("criticalFilename","serviceName","item.itemCode").matching(searchTerm.toLowerCase()+'*').createQuery();

    javax.persistence.Query jpaQuery = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, CriticalComponent.class);

    List<CriticalComponent> criticalComponentsModel = null;
    try {
        criticalComponentsModel  = jpaQuery.getResultList();
    } catch (NoResultException nre) {
        log.debug("Search: No result found");
    }
    return criticalComponentsModel;
}
```